# Этимология слов "радеть", "нерадивый, "рачительный"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слов *радеть*, *нерадивый*, *рачительный*?

1) Являются ли слова *радеть* и *радивый*/*нерадивый*"  однокоренными в современном языке?

2) Слово *рачительный* имеет ли общий исторический корень с этими словами и  от какого глагола происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современном русском языке эти слова (*радеть* и *нерадивый*) не однокоренные, они разминулись, хотя и дальние родственники.

В таком случае говорят:

***слова состоят в историческом (этимологическом) родстве.***

Общий корень - *рад*.

Слово *рачительный* произошло от другого корня - *рач*.

---

Сопоставляем исследования этимологов.

[Этимологический словарь Крылова:](http://www.endic.ru/krylov/Rachiteln-3991.html)

**РАЧИТЕЛЬНЫЙ**

> Это слово, имеющее значение "заботливый", восходит к глаголу *рачити* –
>   "заботиться, думать", в диалектах еще известному.

[Этимологический словарь Шанского:](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Rachiteln-3606.html)

> Искон. Суф. производное от *рачитель* «тот, кто заботится», суф.
>   образования от *рачить* «радеть, заботиться».

[Этимологический словарь Фасмера:](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

> От гл. *рачить*, из праслав., от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   др.-русск., ст.-слав. рачити (θέλειν, βούλεσθαι; Супр.), белор.
>   ра́чыць, болг. ра́ча "хочу", сербохорв. ра́чити "хотеть", словенск.
>   ráčiti, rȃčim "хотеть, благоволить", чешск. ráčit, словацк. ráčiť,
>   польск. raczyć «угощать, потчевать; соизволить, соблаговолить».
>   Вероятно, связано чередованием гласных с реку́, рок, речь. Сравнивают
>   с др.-инд. rаса́уаti "изготовляет, образует, исправляет", rасаnаm ср.
>   р. "порядок, распоряжение", готск. rahnjan "считать".

**НЕРАДИВЫЙ**

[Шанский:](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Neradiv-2286.html)

> Искон. Преф. производное от *радивый* «старательный, усердный», суф.
>   образования от *рад* «старание, усердие, работа», в др. слав. яз. еще
>   известного. См. *радеть*.

**РАДЕТЬ**

[Фасмер:](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)

> Происходит от праслав., от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск.
>   *радити* «заботиться» наряду с *родити, рожу* — то же, неродиıе (ἀμέλεια), неродъ — то же, ст.-слав. *радити, нерадити, нераждѫ
>   (ἀμελεῖν, παρακούειν; Супр.), наряду с родити «заботиться», русск.
>   радеть, болг. радя́, раде́я «забочусь, стараюсь», сербохорв. ра́дити,
>   ра̑ди̑м «стремиться, работать», словенск. róditi, ródim «заботиться,
>   соблюдать», др.-чешск. neroditi «не желать», в.-луж. rodźić «хотеть,
>   стремиться», диал. rodźeć, н.-луж. roźeś, roźim. Родственно др.-инд.
>   rā́dhyati, rādhnṓti «удается, справляется», rā́dhyatē «удается»,
>   rādhayati «совершает», авест. rāđaiti «исправляет», rāda-
>   «попечитель», осет. rād «порядок, ряд», готск. garēdan
>   «предусматривать», др.-сакс. râdan «советовать, замышлять», также
>   готск. rōdjan «говорить», лит. ródyti «показывать», ирл. imm-rā́dim
>   «обдумываю».

[Шанский:](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Radet-3509.html)

> Общеслав. Считается родственным др.-инд. rādhayati «совершает», осет.
>   rād «порядок». *Радеть* первоначально означало, вероятно, «работать»,
>   затем — «стараться» и «заботиться». Ср. *нерадивый* «плохо работающий,
>   не старающийся».